# List of Employees only exist on window refresh

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm looking at some odd code and I reran it to verify it works and for some reason its not and what is happening after I submit my form. Nothing seems to show up in my employeesList but if I refresh the screen then it will show up. Also, if I click the X to delete the user nothing happens and I receive no errors in the console.

Why can't I see the list of my employees unless I refresh my screen?

Why doesn't the employee get removed if I click my delete icon.

js/application.js

```
angular.module("employeesApp",  []).controller("DBController", function ($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.employeeName;
    $scope.employeeStreet;
    $scope.employeeCity;
    $scope.employeeState;
    $scope.employeeZipCode;

    $scope.employeesList = dataService.getEmployees();

    $scope.addEmployee = function() {
        var employee = {
          "employeeName": $scope.employeeName, 
          "employeeStreet": $scope.employeeStreet, 
          "employeeCity": $scope.employeeCity, 
          "employeeState": $scope.employeeState, 
          "employeeZipCode": $scope.employeeZipCode
        };

        dataService.addEmployee(employee);

        $scope.employeeName = '';
        $scope.employeeStreet = '';
        $scope.employeeCity = '';
        $scope.employeeState = '';
        $scope.employeeZipCode = '';
    }

    $scope.deleteEmployee = function(deletedEmployee) {
        dataService.removeEmployee(deletedEmployee);
    }
});
```

js/dataService.js

```
angular.module("employeesApp").service("dataService", function () {

    var employeesList = [];

    this.getEmployees = function () {
        var str = localStorage.getItem("Employees");
        employeesList = JSON.parse(str) || employeesList;
        return employeesList;
    };

    this.addEmployee = function (employee) {
        var employeesList = this.getEmployees();
        employeesList.push(employee);
        var str = JSON.stringify(employeesList);
        localStorage.setItem("Employees", str);
    };

    this.removeEmployee = function (employee) {
        var employeesList = this.getEmployees();
        employeesList.splice(employeesList.indexOf(employee), 1);
        var str = JSON.stringify(employeesList);
        localStorage.setItem("Employees", str);
    };
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Employee Directory</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/application.css">
    </head>

    <body ng-app="employeesApp" ng-controller="DBController">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Employee Directory</h1>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h3>Add an Entry</h2>
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Employee:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeName">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="street">Street:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="street" name="street" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeStreet">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="city">City:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeCity">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="state">State:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="state" name="state" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeState">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="zipcode">Zip Code:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" class="form-control" ng-model="employeeZipCode">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" ng-click="addEmployee()" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6" id="employee-list">
                    <div ng-repeat="employee in employeesList track by $index" class="employee">
                        <div class="employee-header">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                            <strong>{{employee.employeeName}}</strong>
                            <span ng-click="deleteEmployee(employee)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="employee-footer">
                            <address>
                                {{employee.employeeStreet}}<br>
                                {{employee.employeeCity}}, {{employee.employeeState}} {{employee.employeeZipCode}}
                            </address>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/application.js"></script>
        <script src="js/dataService.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: first guess would be in part due to the fact that you have your code loaded even before the `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: What do you mean? Those are all 3 different files.

Comment: Well what you posted shows otherwise, I don't see any indication of where one file would start or the next would begin, so it reads to me being an outsider as something thats all one chunk of the same file, and in that I would say what I did say..

Comment: Fixed to show what code belonged to what file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are setting your scopes employeesList on the initial page load, however you are not re-associating this when you add employees or delete employees. You need to set `$scope.employeesList` every time you modify the data.

```
$scope.employeesList = dataService.getEmployees();
```

Is the line you are setting the data for your scope's view.

Comment: Are you saying copy that line at the bottom of the addEmployee function and deleteEmployee function?

Comment: Worked thank you. Everything else in the code looked fine?

Comment: Not that I can see, but I don't work with angular much.